# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll'

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, dll

I want to connect an SQL Server on my local computer via XAMPP. For that, I am using the following specs:

- XAMPP
- PHP 7.0.15
- SQL Server 2012

I already installed the drivers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and [here](https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/download/details.aspx?id=36434). I also linked the Non thread safe driver `php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll` in the x86 (32-Bit) version. When I now start the apache server via the XAMPP Control Panel, it gives me an error in the `error_log` from apache.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll' - Das angegebene Modul
>   wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

This is a german error message and means that the module was not found.

This is my php.ini file, which will be loaded:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

...

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

So the dll file is located under the default `ext` folder. What is going wrong?

I think there must be a problem, that apache didn't find the dll file. But in the explorer, the dll file has the same name as I write in the php.ini.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 7 unable to initialize sqlsrv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938711/php-7-unable-to-initialize-sqlsrv)

Comment: But I have done this steps. I don't know why apache don't find my dll.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to use the `Thread Safe` version with XAMPP on windows and not the `NTS` version

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer. I heard from an earlier question, that XAMPP uses Non Thread safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get a PHP startup error when you start Apache that means you are running PHP as Apache module. In such case, you should be using the thread-safe version of PHP, as explained in the [Windows download](http://windows.php.net/download/) page:

> With Apache you have to use the Thread Safe (TS) versions of PHP.
>
> TS refers to multithread capable builds. NTS refers to single thread only builds. Use case for **TS binaries** involves interaction with a multithreaded SAPI and **PHP loaded as a module into a web server**. For NTS binaries the widespread use case is interaction with a web server through the FastCGI protocol, utilizing no multithreading (but also for example CLI).